# There aren't any releases for module "commerce_tax"

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal-vm and drupal console, and following the instructions for installing drupal commerce on an existing site (drupal-vm made me a drupal 8 site) here:
http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/install.html
specifically, the command was:
drupal module:install commerce_product commerce_checkout commerce_cart commerce_tax

I received the error in the Title, here's the whole output:

drupal module:install commerce_product commerce_checkout commerce_cart commerce_tax
 One or more modules "commerce_tax" are not available, running download process to get those modules
 Getting releases for module "commerce_tax"

[ERROR] There aren't any releases for module "commerce_tax"

[ERROR] Invalid module name: commerce_tax

Installing module(s) "commerce_product, commerce_checkout, commerce_cart"

[OK] The following module(s) were installed successfully: "commerce_product,
      commerce_checkout, commerce_cart"

// cache:rebuild

Rebuilding cache(s), wait a moment please.

[OK] Done clearing cache(s).

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because commerce_tax is not included in [Commerce 8.x-2.x](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) branch, because of which Drupal Console is not able to find the module.

Comment: Is it available?  Is there a way to implement taxes?